# PyCharm Python not running single unit test

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

When I RMB on a single Python unittest in PyCharm (in the gutter on the green arrow) Pycharm insists on running all the tests in the file.  Am I missing something in the configuration?

Comment: If you do a left click to set the caret within that unit test, and then right click => run (or the run shortcut), it should run only that test. Subsequent selection of the green arrow should then run only that unit test. It's hackish, but I'm not aware of any other way.

Comment: Right. “Should” being the key word there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have corrected itself after I renamed the test case class